# How to only Rerender if not Rendered yet

Tags: visualforce, rerender

I like to render an iFrame in my page if some batches are done.
But only like to render it once.

what I tried before, makes it rerendering all 5 seconds:

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:actionPoller rerender="iFrame,someOthers" interval="5" action="{!updateProgress}" />
    <apex:someCode id="someOthers"/>
    <apex:iframe src="{!frameUrl}" id="iframe" height="50px" width="100%" rendered="{!loadFrame}" />
</apex:form>
```

So What I'm looking for should do something like:

```
if (someWorkDone && iFrame is not shown yet)
    iFrame rendered = true; (but never rerender it)
```

EDIT:
Solution with help of Adrian & Tim:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="container">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:actionPoller rendered="{!NOT(frameShown)}" rerender="container" interval="5" action="{!updateProgress}" />
        <apex:actionPoller rendered="{!frameShown}" rerender="someOthers" interval="5" action="{!updateProgress}" />
        <apex:someCode id="someOthers"/>
        <apex:iframe src="{!frameUrl}" id="iframe" height="50px" width="100%" rendered="{!frameShown}" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give your `<apex:form>` tag an id, you can rerender that and have `updateProgress` set some sort of flag variable. Something like:

```
<apex:form id="apexForm">
    <apex:actionPoller rendered="{!alreadyRerendered}" rerender="someOthers" interval="5" action="{!updateProgress}" />
    <apex:actionPoller rendered="{!NOT(alreadyRendered)}" rerender="apexForm" interval="5" action="{!updateProgress}" />
    <apex:someCode id="someOthers"/>
    <apex:iframe src="{!frameUrl}" id="iframe" height="50px" width="100%" rendered="{!loadFrame}" />
</apex:form>
```

Then just have your `updateProgress` method set`alreadyRendered = true`.

Comment: I've seen ie compatibility issues rerendering the form. You might be better off wrapping the contents of the from in an outputPanel with an id and rerendering it.

Comment: Absolutely. I just wanted to minimize the number of tweaks I made in my code.

Comment: All right, thanks both of you, I gonna upload my answer, i was able to reduce size of variables to 1.